# using ajax and jquery to populate a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, post

i'm learning jquery (using 1.10). i'm using ajax to parse an xml dynamicly generated by php by posting a number, for example if you post n=3 you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<list>
<item>item 1</item>
<item>item 2</item>
<item>item 3</item>
</list>
```

i can receive the response and parse the text as xml, i wrote this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn1").click(function() {
                $.post("jq.php",{"n" : $("#v").val()},function(d,s) {
                    $("#div1").html("<ul>");
                    $(d).children().each(function(i,e) {
                        $("#div1").append("<li>"+$(e).text()+"</li>");
                    });
                    $("#div1").append("</ul>");
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="v" />
    <div id="div1">JQuery test</div>
    <button id="btn1">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and it works... it receives teh output and creates the list, but it adds the  before adding all the 
`<li>` to code, for example:

```
<ul></ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li>
```

i know, ajax functions returns inmediately and doesn't block the script

how can i fix this? .queue()? or how?

Comment: Sounds like a major x/y problem to me. Why aren't you just creating the markup directly with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the LI's to the DIV, not to the UL.

You **can not** just append half an element, it's all or nothing, so you can't append an opening tag, and then later on the closing tag, elements are appended as objects :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").on('click', function() {
        $.post("jq.php",{"n" : $("#v").val()}, function(d,s) {

            var ul = $('<ul />');

            $(d).children().each(function(i,e) {
                ul.append("<li>"+$(e).text()+"</li>");
            });

            $("#div1").html(ul);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... does  var ul = $('<ul />'); create any element? for example $('<form />'); or $('<a />');?

Comment: Yes, it creates a new `<ul></ul>` element